# How do I create a Forms Library feature with a custom list definition?

Tags: 2007, forms-library, spsource, list-definition

I'm working on a prototype SharePoint site at the moment where a forms library has been created with an InfoPath form published to it. A content type has not been used, the form is bound directly to the forms library. This now needs to be put into a redeployable feature and solution package.

I tried SPSource but the list definition it produced deploys as a document library. I also tried adapting MS' XmlFormLibrary feature with the same result.

Is it possible to create your own Form Library list definition and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that environmental issues caused this problem. SPSource works fine for this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried the **SharePoint Solution Generator** that is part of ["Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Tools"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7bf65b28-06e2-4e87-9bad-086e32185e68&displaylang=en#Overview)
It will generate the list definition for you based an existing "list/Form Library" and also creates a c# project.